# Most efficient way to concatenate strings JavaScript in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

Let say you have a for loop and you want to build a string in a very specific way using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

I've find 2 similar ways to do it.

```
let text = ''
words = ['Hello', 'world']
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    text += `${words[i]} || `
}
```

Or

```
let text = ''
words = ['Hello', 'world']
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    text = `${text}${words[i]} || `
}
```

Both produce the same output (Hello || world || )

Is any difference in performance or standard?

Comment: You can compare performance at https://jsperf.com/

Comment: Add this `['Hello', 'world'].concat('').join(" || ")` as a task to measure performance.

Comment: Another performance comparer: http://jsben.ch/FskS4

Comment: "Which is more efficient" questions often don't age well. Joining arrays instead of repeated string concatenation used to be the right answer, but then browser venders optimized the latter, making that more efficient. The answer will be different from JS engine to JS engine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `words.join(" || ")+" || "` today is the fastest way, see this http://jsben.ch/DlXOa , as @jacob points out, it is a relative conclusion. But, as a general rule in JavaScript, usually built-in methods are faster.